# Compatibility issue when using android app in both phone and tablet

Tags: android

Compatibility issue  when using android app in both phone and tablet
and
image using background  of  some views  then image get stretched fit the screen size
and some time resolution also lost and will not work good in bigger screen.

Comment: different drawable   folder need different resolution of the image ... there is any ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compatibility issue  generally  arises when our application is 
downloaded in to device with different  screen size and  resolution 
so first basic problem happen in tablet activity not  use space efficient  so
we have to use fragment also. and the second problem may come in image scaling and re sizing so we have to use 9patch   tool  and third problem may come  if we use hard coded and absolute pixel in xml layout file so please avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956014/why-should-we-use-xml-layouts)

For managing images i use to do the following:

-Put your highest resolution of the image at the -nodpi folder

-Use code to scale it so that the image width matches the screen width

-Put it at the imageview and use ScaleType.Matrix but dont set a matrix

Your image will fit perfectly, but, you still need to take care of the aspect ratio.

My approach is to desing images at 16/9 and let know the designer that the bottom of the image (usually between <1.5,1.7>) will not be shown on devices with less aspect ratio so he will not put relevant design elements on it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Please read these Documents and apply :-

[http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html