# I am implementing an app and making Size competibility

Tags: android

I am making an android application and implementing a table so I am making all Text Boxes and Edit Boxes dynamically and also giving their Text Size dynamically 
but it is not coming according to their device size. Please help me thanks in advance.
I wanted to make my app size compatible according to device.

```
tbrow = new TableRow(context);
        tbrow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 45));
        // tbrow.setPadding(5, 0, 5,0);
        // serial no.
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);

        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        if (buttonchangeCount > 0 && i < saveDataCount) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("loans_id"));
            receiptId.add("" + id);
            tv.setText(id + "");
        } else {
            tv.setText((addButtCount) + "");
        }
        tv.setPadding(10, 10, 5, 10);
        tv.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.mainColor));
        if (Login.width >= 1000) {
            tv.setTextSize(25);
            tv.setWidth(121);
        } else if (Login.width >= 480 && Login.width < 1000) {
            tv.setTextSize(15);
            tv.setWidth(242);
            tv.setHeight(96);

        } else if (Login.width >= 320 && Login.width < 480)
            tv.setTextSize(12);
        tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape_color);
        sr_no.add(tv);
        tbrow.addView(tv);
        // Bank loan type.
        final Button butt = new Button(context);
        butt.setId(i);

        butt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        butt.setPadding(5, 10, 5, 10);
        bankLoanType.add(butt);

        if (buttonchangeCount > 0 && i < saveDataCount) {
            String str = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("loan_type"));
            butt.setText(str);
            loanstatuslist.clear();
            loanstatuslist.add("New");
            loanstatuslist.add("Renew");
            int id1 = butt.getId();
            if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("loan_type")).equalsIgnoreCase("Term Loan(TL)")) {
                loanstatuslist.remove(1);
                loan_status1.get(id1).setText("New");
            }
            // } else {
            // //loan_status1.get(id1).setText("Select Loan Status");
            // }
            //
        } else {
            // butt.setText("Select Loan Type");
        }
        butt.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.mainColor));

        if (Login.width >= 1000) {
            butt.setTextSize(25);
            butt.setWidth(300);
        } else if (Login.width >= 480 && Login.width < 1000)

        {
            butt.setTextSize(14);
            butt.setWidth(604);
            butt.setHeight(92);
        } else if (Login.width >= 320 && Login.width < 480)
            butt.setTextSize(12);
        butt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape_color);
        butt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final int id11 = butt.getId();
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                View layout = BankLoanFragment.this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view,
                        BankLoanFragment.this.container, false);
                ListView listView = (ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listView);
                final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Cash Credit Limit(CCL)");
                list.add("Term Loan(TL)");
                OnlyTextAdapter adapter = new OnlyTextAdapter(context, list);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                builder.setView(layout);
                final AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        butt.setText(list.get(position).toString());
                        String bt = butt.getText().toString();
                        final int id1 = butt.getId();
                        Log.d("bankLoan", "id1=" + id1);
                        // =
                        // bankLoanType.get(id1).getText().toString().trim();
                        //

                        if (bt.equals("Select Loan Type")
                                && (loanNumber.get(id1).getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0)) {
                            Log.d("bankLoan", "in IF case");
                            cmnBehave.alertMsg("Select Loan type and LoanNumber first.", "Loan Status");
                            // ad.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            loanstatuslist.clear();
                            String str = loan_status1.get(id1).getText().toString();
                            loanstatuslist.add("New");
                            loanstatuslist.add("Renew");
                            if (bt.equals("Term Loan(TL)")) {
                                loanstatuslist.remove(1);
                                loan_status1.get(id1).setText("New");
                                // ad.dismiss();
                            } else
                                loan_status1.get(id1).setText(str);
                        }

                        ad.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                // if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("bank_loan_status")))
                if (dbutil.getnewStatusIsExists(shgid, meetingDate,
                        (loanNumber.get(id11).getText().toString().trim())) == 0) {
                    // cmnBehave.alertMsg("You have already taken Loan, you
                    // can renew Loan.", "Action");
                    ad.show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: don't set fix height width to your views. instead set wrap_content and match_parent.

Comment: read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33498221/compatibility-issue-when-using-android-app-in-both-phone-and-tablet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34996396/2826147

Comment: @AmitVaghela actually I want to work with Text Size of text view not work with textview size

Comment: In that i have mentioned two official links please visit that you will get answer @user3839710

Answer (score 0):

You can Use one Layout file to Use the all the Screens.

[image: one Layout for all screens]

In above Picture the layout file is one for all screens by the Use the different `values`(dimens) folder.

```
values-w320dp ===> For Mobiles

values-w480dp ===> For 7 inch Tablets

values-w820dp ===> For 9 and 10 Tablets
```

The same `drawable` like in the Picture

```
drawable-normal-hdpi ==>For Mobiles

drawable-large-hdpi ==>For 7 inch Tablets

drawable-xlarge ==>For 9 and 10 Tablets
```

In Layout File :

```
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_edittext"
```

the login_edittext must be mention in all dimens folder at respective values

In `values-w320dp` inside the dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="login_edittext">15dp</dimen>
```

In `values-w480dp` inside the dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="login_edittext">30dp</dimen>
```

In `values-w820dp` inside the dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="login_edittext">40dp</dimen>
```

I think It will be help you..

Comment: thanks for giving me immediate response but i want to set Text size of table textview   dynamically when i am implementing table.

Comment: @user3839710 can you add your layout.xml file to your post?

Comment: it is going dynamically by code not by the layout so please focus on given code and please tell me here what should i do.

Comment: tv.setTextSize(25) instead of this statement what should i write here

Answer (score 0):

If you are dynamically creating views then you should use **Display Metrics**. And check device width and height dynamically and based on that give weights to your dynamic views.

Use below code for getting screen width and height.

**Code**

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

ALSO check below links if helpful for you :)
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207470/adding-table-rows-dynamically-in-android)

[link 2](https://technotzz.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/android-dynamically-add-rows-to-table-layout/)

Comment: I have already perform this operation and after this I am giving sizes according to their size but it doesn't work for me

Comment: can you please add screen shot of your app screen