# Different layouts for different screen density

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to figure out how to define different layout for different screen density.

At the moment I have to manage a 7" (Nexus 7), 10" (galaxy tab S) and now a 9.7" (Galaxy tab A) tablets

So I've defined for now two layouts directories :

```
layout       (for 7")
layout-sw720dp (should be only for 10")
```

My problem is the 9.7" tablet match the layout-sw720dp directory as my 10" tablet. So from this point I don't know how to define another layout directory based only on my 9.7" tablet.

The density of the `10"` is `288ppi` and the density of the `9.7"` is `132ppi`. 
I guess if the density would be the same I wouldn't have this problem.

Is it possible to create a new directory layout based only on the density ? What is the best practice for this use case and manage at the same time my 10" layout and my 9.7" layout with a different density ?

Comment: "I'm trying to figure how to define different layout for different screen density" -- IMHO, that's a code smell.

Comment: Maybe its useful for you taking a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956014/why-should-we-use-xml-layouts

Comment: Of course you can use the folders mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi for the layouts as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is instead of using layout-sw720dp I used these two layouts:

```
layout-hpdi for 10" with hight dpi
layout-mdpi for 9.7 with medium dpi
```

And it seems to work good.

**Edit**

Actually I kept `layout-sw720dp` and then I use also a `value-hdpi` and `value-mdpi` resource directories to manage at the same time screen size and density.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options for this either you use

layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
layout-sw800dp

or use the dpi wise folder structure like this

drawable-land-mdpi
drawable-land-hdpi
drawable-land-xhdpi
drawable-land-xxhdpi