# Identify devices uniquely with same density and screen size category but different screen size in inches

Tags: android

Hi Ive been creating UI's for quite some time based on screen densities and screen size categories.

Now I have a weird situation where I have an Android Tablet(8 inches) and a HP Slate(21 inches) with MDPI density and X-Large screen size category.

Can someone please guide me on how the UI's could be created for these devices uniquely though they have the same Android UI specs?

Comment: You can take a look at this or keep wasting hours with this kind of problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956014/why-should-we-use-xml-layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a weird situation where I have an Android Tablet(8 inches) and a HP Slate(21 inches) with MDPI density and X-Large screen size category.

IMHO, your Android tablet is messed up, as an 8" tablet should be `-large`, not `-xlarge`. That being said, your underlying point would be valid for, say, a 10.1" tablet, compared with the HP Slate, Samsung Galaxy View (18"), etc.

Also, the Slate 21" really should be `-ldpi`, but let's assume that HP elected to categorize it as `-mdpi`.

> Can someone please guide me on how the UI's could be created for these devices uniquely though they have the same Android UI specs?

Ignore `-large` and `-xlarge`, as they have been obsolete for a while.

Instead, use `-wNNNdp`, `-hNNNdp`, and `-swNNNdp` qualifiers, where NNN are values that you choose, measured in density-independent pixels (`dp`).

An 8" `-mdpi` tablet will have a modest resolution (e.g., WXGA, 1280x720). The HP Slate 21" has a 1080p display (1920x1080). `1dp`==`1px` for `-mdpi` devices, so the 8" tablet has a width of `1280dp` and the Slate 21" has a width of `1980dp`.

So, `res/layout-w1800dp/`, for example, would be picked up by the Slate 21" but not your 8" tablet, as the current width of the 8" tablet will not be `1800dp` or larger.

Comment: Now that makes more sense. Looks like I will have to revisit the the Android UI guidelines once again. Thank you so much.