# Android : 5 Buttons positions : The better way?

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to fix 5 Buttons like the pictures. But I place the five Buttons with the position of Nexus 6. I realize I lost 1 hour when i try this code on Nexus 10 : All the buttons were in a different positions !

What is the better way to fix 5 buttons and all positions will be ok with all devices /screen .

Will the following layout work?

```
RelativeLayout
   Linear1  ( for the first 2 buttons )
   Linear 2 ( for the 2 buttons next buttons )
   Linear 3 ( for the last button  )
/RelativeLayout
```

[image: Button Layout]

I repeat my question because I was not clear : How can I put a Button on a specific position ? For example : I want to put My GreenButton at 70% of the screen from the top, and 50 of the screen from the right / left

Comment: The best way is not using xml files. take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956014/why-should-we-use-xml-layouts

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `RelativeLayout` with attributes such as `android:layout_alignParentTop`, `android:layout_centerVertical` and other similar alignment attributes. They allow you to specifically place the buttons in your layout to get the desired effect. Here is the result:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.yourpackage.FiveButtonActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button4"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button5"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i have a problem. I have a back ground picture, and I Have to put the button Exactly on a specific position of the background picture. For exemple : I have to put the first button at X =100 ,y = 350.

I have an idea : How can I take the Actual Device Screen size. Then I can do the followings things : Button.X = ScreenDevice * 0.60 Button.Y = ScreenDevice * 0.60

Answer (score 1):

Try using **PercentRelativeLayout**. You can give percentage for views, very useful for your case. Recently added to support library.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Example:

```
 <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>

 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

The attributes that you can use are:

```
layout_widthPercent
layout_heightPercent
layout_marginPercent
layout_marginLeftPercent
layout_marginTopPercent
layout_marginRightPercent
layout_marginBottomPercent
layout_marginStartPercent
layout_marginEndPercent
layout_aspectRatio
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this, i juste update androïd studio because I think I did not have the recent library

Comment: Did you notice the Layout start with  <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout and finish with
 </android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout/> ? That make an error on Androïd Studio

Comment: @user198948 Copied from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html Maybe there is a mistake, try closing it with **</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>**

Comment: I am sorry, i begin in Android programming. When I paste the PercentRelativeLayout code, a rendering problem appear " the The following classes could not be found:"

Comment: @user198948 Did you add Support Library to your Project?

Comment: I am a beginner, so I read this http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html, I Install it, but I think it is not the good Support library. ( sorry for my poor english ) It is not enough http://hpics.li/b335ea5

Comment: @user198948 I can see you are a beginner, you need to read more tutorials about android developing before starting a real application development. This platform is for more specific programming questions.