# How to set ScrollView with weight of height

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set the screen with two parts, one part has `Imageview` and the other part has `ScrollView`, so I set weight on height to 0.4 in `Imageview` and 0.6 in `Scrollview`. Now I have some horizontal `LinearLayout` in `ScrollView` with two components, `ImageView` and `TextView`.

Now I want the same height of all layouts if it has less content.

So how do I implement this feature?

I have attached here with a screenshot so you can understand exactly what I want [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgHEX.png).

Here in the screenshot, the first image view content 0.4 weight height 0.6 weight to `ScrollView`.

`ScrollView` has four `LinearLayout` with `Imageview` and `TextView`.
In this last three layouts max content layout height, I want it same in the other two layouts. If that layout has less content still I want the same height.

[image]

In the second image you can see the problem which I faced.

Comment: Please consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956014/why-should-we-use-xml-layouts

Answer (score 0):

I created one example regarding to your explanation.

If you have more same layouts then you can create separate layout for it and Include that layout where you want.

Have look at this example.

[image]

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/android" >
    </ImageView>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text " />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text " />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="long text long text long text long text " />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text " />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text " />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text " />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text " />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/google_plus" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="4"
                    android:text="long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text " />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<ScrollView
 layoutWeight = "your layout weight">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/container">
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">Your Content</linearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">Your Content</linearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">Your Content</linearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">Your Content</linearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: You cannot add multiple layouts on a ScrollView.

Comment: cekistezeytin there is no multiple layouts, look closely