# How to reduce layout loading time of a complex layout with custom views in android?

Tags: android, performance

I have an activity and a fragment. Where fragment will be loaded dynamically in activity. Fragment has around 20 views and most of them are custom views. For loading the fragment its taking around 3 seconds, this time is just for loading the layout, without any initialization or functionality. I feel 3 seconds is more and want to reduce it to 1 second. What could be the possible ways to achieve this.
    Things I did:
    ** Removed weights and nested layouts.
    ** Removed unused attributes of view
    ** Flattened the layout hierarchy. 
Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:gauge="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.test.app.testApp"
xmlns:customview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_light_grey" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_components_dummy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="135dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ dummy_layout"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/host_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dummy_parent"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/water_and_drain_tactile"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/dummy_parent_water"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >
                <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView
                    android:id="@+id/level_indicator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/empty_indiactor"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </FrameLayout>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/dummy_parent_drain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp" >
                <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView
                    android:id="@+id/drain_level_indicator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/xyz" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/empty_indiactor"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Waterdummy_TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dummyCenter"
            android:text="Water"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <View
            android:id="@+id/dummyCenter"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#00ffffff" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Draindummy_TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dummyCenter"
            android:text="Drain"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/host_layout"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/host_Stop_Background"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/xyz"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dull_stop_icon"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/host_stop_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/host_stop_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:text="STOP"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/host_Rate_Layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/host_Stop_Background" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/host_Rate_Icon"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/xyz"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/host_rate_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/host_rate_unit_textView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:text="1.5"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="34sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/host_system_Icon"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/host_Stop_Background"
            android:background="@drawable/host_system_top_tactile"
            android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:paddingTop="18dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dull_rate_layout"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/host_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/dull_rate_layout"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dull_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dull_rate"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/xyz" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dull_rate_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/dull_rate_unit_textView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:text="500"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="36sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dull_rate_unit_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:text="mL/min"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/salad_layout"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dull_rate_layout" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/salad_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/salad"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/salad_Icon"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/dull_salad_tactile"
                android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
                android:paddingBottom="18dp"
                android:paddingTop="18dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/midLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="460dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_components_dummy" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/boomSpeed_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/boom_speed"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/boomSpeed_Value_Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boomSpeed_textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:text="300"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_down"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/boomSpeed_Value_Text"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/boomSpeed_Value_Text"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_up"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/boomSpeed_Value_Text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/boomSpeed_Value_Text"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/boom_Speed_Value_Unit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boomSpeed_Value_Text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:text="mL/min"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#444444" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IV_boomSpeed"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/boom_Speed_Value_Unit"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/IV_boomSpeed"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="380dip"
            android:layout_height="380dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
        <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView1
            android:id="@+id/circularprogressbar2"
            android:layout_width="345dip"
            android:layout_height="345dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            customview:cpb_backgroundColor="#EDEDED"
            customview:cpb_borderColor="#22B7B3"
            customview:cpb_maintitle="@string/time_remaining"
            customview:cpb_progressColor="#22B7B3" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/clickablearea"
            android:layout_width="180dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/circularprogressbar2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
            android:background="#00fff000" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IV_boomSpeed"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="380dip"
            android:layout_height="380dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/dialsbg" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IV_StopML"
            android:layout_width="120dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
            android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="STOP\n ML"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView1
            android:id="@+id/circularprogressbar3"
            android:layout_width="345dip"
            android:layout_height="345dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            customview:cpb_borderColor="#E7AB0F"
            customview:cpb_progressColor="#e2a000"
            customview:backgroundColor="#EDEDED"
            customview:goal="@string/goal"
            customview:goal_unit="mL"
            customview:goal_value="2800"
            customview:ml_unit="mL"
            customview:rate="@string/rate"
            customview:rate_unit="mL/hr"
            customview:rate_value="700"
            customview:removed_title="@string/removed"
            customview:removed_value="1500" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/editMLGoal_clickArea"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/circularprogressbar3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dip"
            android:background="#00fff000" >
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/editMLRate_clickArea"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/circularprogressbar3"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dip"
            android:background="#00fff000" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_DialView2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView2
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        gauge:isFloat="false"
        gauge:scaleEndValue="400"
        gauge:scaleMaxLimit="350"
        gauge:scaleMinLimit="150"
        gauge:scaleStartValue="70"
        gauge:showLimitText="true"
        gauge:showNeedle="true"
        gauge:showRanges="true"
        gauge:showScale="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textTitle="@string/ven"
        gauge:textUnit="mmHg"
        gauge:textUnitColor="#000000"
        gauge:textValueColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_DialView1"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/RL_DialView2" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView2
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        gauge:isFloat="false"
        gauge:scaleEndValue="500"
        gauge:scaleMaxLimit="400"
        gauge:scaleMinLimit="-200"
        gauge:scaleStartValue="-300"
        gauge:showLimitText="true"
        gauge:showNeedle="true"
        gauge:showRanges="true"
        gauge:showScale="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textTitle="@string/art"
        gauge:textUnit="mmHg"
        gauge:textUnitColor="#000000"
        gauge:textValueColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_DialView4"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_DialView2" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView2
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        gauge:isFloat="true"
        gauge:scaleEndValue="40"
        gauge:scaleMaxLimit="38"
        gauge:scaleMinLimit="36"
        gauge:scaleStartValue="34"
        gauge:showLimitText="true"
        gauge:showNeedle="true"
        gauge:showRanges="true"
        gauge:showScale="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textTitle="@string/dt"
        gauge:textUnit="\u2103"
        gauge:textUnitColor="#000000"
        gauge:textValueColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_DialView3"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/RL_DialView1" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView2
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        gauge:isFloat="false"
        gauge:scaleEndValue="320"
        gauge:scaleMaxLimit="300"
        gauge:scaleMinLimit="90"
        gauge:scaleStartValue="70"
        gauge:showLimitText="true"
        gauge:showNeedle="true"
        gauge:showRanges="true"
        gauge:showScale="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textTitle="@string/tmp"
        gauge:textUnit="mmHg"
        gauge:textUnitColor="#000000"
        gauge:textValueColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_DialView5"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/RL_DialView4" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView2
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        gauge:isFloat="true"
        gauge:scaleEndValue="17"
        gauge:scaleMaxLimit="15.9"
        gauge:scaleMinLimit="13.1"
        gauge:scaleStartValue="12"
        gauge:showInnerRim="false"
        gauge:showNeedle="true"
        gauge:showRanges="true"
        gauge:showScale="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textTitle="@string/cond"
        gauge:textUnit="mS/cm"
        gauge:textUnitColor="#000000"
        gauge:textValueColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show us your xml, maybe we can help u.

Comment: By not having to call findViewById should be a good answer

Comment: @Nanoc Could you please elaborate what you are trying to say.

Comment: Done it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956014/why-should-we-use-xml-layouts

Comment: @Nanoc Thank you. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @RobertBanyai Updated the layout. Please have a look.

Comment: I think you use to much unnecessary relative layout. Its really increase the depth, and it can cause your loading time.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [`Layout Optimizating`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/index.html) guide:

1. Avoid nested `ViewGroup`. You should make your `Layout` as low-level hierarchy as possible

> Using nested instances of LinearLayout can lead to an excessively deep view hierarchy. Furthermore, nesting several instances of LinearLayout that use the layout_weight parameter can be especially expensive as each child needs to be measured twice. This is particularly important when the layout is inflated repeatedly, such as when used in a ListView or GridView.

2. It is always good practice to run the lint tool on your layout files to search for possible view hierarchy optimizations.
3. Using `ViewStub`:

> Sometimes your layout might require complex views that are rarely used. Whether they are item details, progress indicators, or undo messages, you can reduce memory usage and speed up rendering by loading the views only when they are needed

Answer (score 0):

Using RelativeLayouts are expensive, as laying out the views is a 'complex' task - each time you inflate the xml, the inflater must calculate the relations between the views, which is rather expensive.

You should try to use as much LinearLayouts as you can. This will boost things up a bit. LinearLayouts are much more faster to inflates, as the relations are at most 2 nodes per view.

Comment: Thank you. Was using LinearLayout earlier, but that required too many nesting to create the desired UI. So, again nested layout is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard from CustomViews?
You can lay out the child views directly. So it don't need calculate again and again and again.
For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RL_DialView2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-40dp" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/xyz" />
    <com.test.app.ui.components.CustomView2
        android:id="@+id/gauge_view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        gauge:isFloat="false"
        gauge:scaleEndValue="400"
        gauge:scaleMaxLimit="350"
        gauge:scaleMinLimit="150"
        gauge:scaleStartValue="70"
        gauge:showLimitText="true"
        gauge:showNeedle="true"
        gauge:showRanges="true"
        gauge:showScale="false"
        gauge:showText="true"
        gauge:textTitle="@string/ven"
        gauge:textUnit="mmHg"
        gauge:textUnitColor="#000000"
        gauge:textValueColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is 5 times in your Layout.
Change the RelativeLayout to a `ImageWithCustomView2Layout` which extends from `ViewGroup`.
Then override `onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)` and `onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`.

However. When you use CustomViews which know exactly the position (and size) of its Childs it will be much faster.

Learn more about CustomViews at:
[DAC](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/custom-views/index.html) or 
GitHub Examples [(1)](https://github.com/StefMa/CustomViews), [(2)](https://github.com/passsy/android-CustomViewTutorial)

Our can also a look at [this post](https://medium.com/google-developers/simplify-complex-view-hierarchies-5d358618b06f) at medium.